# Swift - Is there any performance differences in putting import in the beginning of the file vs somewhere in the middle?

Tags: swift

Would there be drawbacks in performance when I arrange my codes as,

```
import Foundation

class Foo { }

import SomethingElse

extension Foo: SomethingElse { }
```

compared to putting all the imported modules at the beginning of the file?

```
import Foundation
import SomethingElse

class Foo { }

extension Foo: SomethingElse { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't matter, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7)

> Most Swift files in your app are order-independent, meaning you can
>   use a type before it is defined, and can even import modules at the
>   bottom of the file (although that is not recommended Swift style.)

Answer (score 2):

Basically packages are imported at the top of usable classes to write code in a more optimized way, *while importing those packages in middle doesn't raise any issue but sure effects the compiler way to compile files*.

```
import Foundation

class Foo { 
    // if raises any exception here below code wait for compilation until handle it.
}

import SomethingElse      // import when make sense with //MARK:  

extension Foo: SomethingElse { 

}
```

This could be a modern way of programming ahead because optimized code changes always makes program better.